# Kibana WebUI loading forever

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I installed ELK 7.01 (ElasticStach, Logstash and Kibana) on a Windows Server 2012 R2. My configuration is as follows ("priv" is our private network):

**kibana.yml**:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: elastic.priv
server.name: "Kibana 7.0.1"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://elastic.priv:9200"]
```

**elasticsearch.yml**:

```
network.host: elastic.priv
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
```

When i try to access http://elastic.priv:5601/app/kibana on the server, it works as intended.

But when I try to acess it from another computer in the local network, I get a white page loading forever (no visible error).

With Google Chrome DevTools, in the Network tab, I see the content being downloaded for several minutes with a "*200 OK*" status, then it expires and becomes "*(failed) net:ERR_CONNECTION_RESET*". But Chrome is still displaying a blank page, with no error.

[image]

I couldn't find other people with the same problem on official forums. Is there a mistake in my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a security audit on our firewall (Stormshield), we found out that its DPI module was blocking traffic.